Godot C++ GDExtension : _process print when editor not running
Since some days, I try to create a Godot project using C++ instead of GDScript with GDExtension. I precise that I'm a beginner in C++ with only basics.
I'd create a node called "Personnage" and I can instance it in the Godot editor.
This is my code :
Personnage.cpp :
#include "Personnage.h"
#include <godot_cpp/core/class_db.hpp>

#include <godot_cpp/variant/utility_functions.hpp>
#include <godot_cpp/godot.hpp>
#include <godot_cpp/classes/engine.hpp>


using namespace godot;

void Personnage::_bind_methods() {
}

Personnage::Personnage() {
    UtilityFunctions::print("Bonjour depuis GDExtension avec C++ !");
}

Personnage::~Personnage() {
}


void Personnage::_ready(){
    UtilityFunctions::print("fonction Start()");
}

void Personnage::_process(double delta) {
    UtilityFunctions::print("fonction Update()");
}

Personnage.h :
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H
#define PERSONNAGE_H

#include <godot_cpp/classes/character_body2d.hpp>

namespace godot {

    class Personnage : public CharacterBody2D {
        GDCLASS(Personnage, CharacterBody2D);
    
    private:
    
    protected:
        static void _bind_methods();
    
    public:
        Personnage();
        ~Personnage();

        void _ready() override;
        void _process(double delta) override;
    };

}

#endif

However, when I put my node in editor hierarchie, the print appear while I not play the game !
The only solution that I found is to add this condition to my _ready() and _process() functions :
void Personnage::_ready(){
    if (!Engine::get_singleton()->is_editor_hint())
    {
        UtilityFunctions::print("fonction Start()");
    }
}

void Personnage::_process(double delta) {
    if (!Engine::get_singleton()->is_editor_hint())
    {
        UtilityFunctions::print("fonction Update()");
    }
}

I'm not satisfying with that because I don't want to add this each time I add one of this two functions in a script.
I want another solution to only have messages in editor's console when my game is running.
Thank you for your help !
